# Find the general solution to the second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Find the general solution to the following ODE:

$$y''-\frac{3}{x}y'+\frac{3}{x^2}y=x^2e^x$$

**My working so far:**
Clearly this is a second order, non-homogeneous equation. The equation follows the form:
$$a(x)y''+b(x)y'+c(x)y=g(x)$$
Thus, the general solution for this can be written as:
$$y=y_h+y_p$$
yh:

yh is given by the solution to the homogeneous ODE a(x)y''+b(x)y'+c(x)y=0. So,

$$y''-\frac{3}{x}y'+\frac{3}{x^2}y=0$$
$$r^2-\frac{3}{x}r+\frac{3}{x^2}=0$$

**The problem is that I don't know how to find the values for r**

I am also confused about how to find **yp (the particular solution).**

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's Cauchy Euler's equation

Answer (score 1):

$$y''-\frac{3}{x}y'+\frac{3}{x^2}y=x^2e^x$$
multiply by $x^2$
$$x^2y''-3xy'+3y=x^4e^x$$
this is  Cauchy-Euler Equation [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still unsure where to go with this. If I try and find yh using the homogenous equation I still don't know how to find r.

Comment: Oh, i've got it now, thanks for the help.

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your eqaution has not constant coefficients so that method won't work.
Note that:

$$y''-\frac{3}{x}y'+\frac{3}{x^2}y=x^2e^x$$
$$ \frac{y''}{x^2} - \frac{2y'}{x^3} - \frac{y'}{x^3} + \frac{3y}{x^4} =e^x$$
$$\left ( \frac{y'}{x^2} \right)'- \left ( \frac{y}{x^3} \right)'=e^x$$
Integrate.
$$\left ( \frac{y'}{x^2} \right)- \left ( \frac{y}{x^3} \right)=e^x+c_1$$
$$\left ( \frac{xy'-y}{x^2} \right)=xe^x+c_1x$$
$$\left ( \frac{y}{x} \right)'=xe^x+c_1x$$
Integrate
$$y=xe^x(x-1)+cx^3+c_2x$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2Y''-3xY'+3Y=x^2e^{x}=f(x)~~~(1)$$
First solve the homogeneous part
$$x^2y''-3xy'+3y=0.~~~~(2)$$
Let $y=x^m$
$$m(m-1)-3m+3=0 \implies m^2-4m+3 \implies m=3,1,$$
So the solutions are $y_1=C_1 x, y_2=C_2 x^3$
Next we vary $C_1,C_2$ as $C_1(x), C_2(x)$.
$$Y(x)=C_1(x) x+C_2(x) x^3~~~(3)$$
The wronskian of $w(x)=y_1,y'_2-y'_1 y_2=w=2x^3$
where $$C_1(x)=-\int \frac{x^2y_2(x) f(x)}{w(x)} dx+D_1=\frac{1}{2}\int x^4  e^x dx+D_1$$ $$=-\frac{1}{2}[(x^4-4x^3+12x^2-24x+24)]e^x+D_1$$
$$C_2(x)=\int x^2 \frac{y_1(x) f(x)}{w(x)}dx+D_2=\frac{1}{2} \int x^2e^x dx+ D_2=\frac{(x^2-2x+2)e^x}{2}+D_2$$ Putting them in (3). we get the total solution of (1).